# Spring boot 2.1.9 - CriteriaBuilder javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

Tags: java, criteriaquery

I use CriteriaQuery, Spring boot 2.1.9, java 11. My code is below:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Order> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Order.class);
Root<Order> from = criteriaQuery.from(Order.class);
Predicate filter = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
// [...]
criteriaQuery.where(filter);
TypedQuery<Order> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

And my config looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=30
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
```

It works fine. But after service run at mode idelTime (overnight do not request to server).
And now if have request come it causes the Error below:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions (142)  
The last packet successfully received from the server was 40,157,504 
milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was
40,157,505 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value
of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing
connection validity before use in your application, increasing the 
server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J 
connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1515)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor425.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:263)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at  ...
```

How to resolve it?
please help me. Thank in advance.

Comment: No.... It not resolve. Today, It happened again. What is solution for that???

Comment: and more exception:
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions (142) - The last packet successfully received from the server was 40,157,504 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 40,157,505 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved.
I changed config and add autoReconnect to URL of DataSource.
used:
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;
replace for:
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;